# How do I separate String and Integer variables in same one resources

Tags: c++

I'm bit hardly to separate the variable String and Integer to passed in "if()"  statement.
I have two variable `"buffString"` and `"buffInteger"`, when i put the buffString in the "if()" statement, I wanna to take String "Data Stop" in the buffString variable, and then set to the RichEdit to showing "Data Stop", but the problem when the `buffInteger` filled same as `buffString` its error come in the process. and compilers say `"Data Stop"` is not valid Integer value

```
void __fastcall TfrmServer::ComPort1RxChar(TObject *Sender, int Count)
{
 String buff;
 ComPort1->ReadStr(buff,255);
 BUF_RX->Data_suhu = buff; // source
 int bufferInteger;
 String bufferString;

 try{
     if(!buff.IsEmpty())
     {
       bufferInteger = StrToInt(BUF_RX->Data_suhu);
       bufferString = BUF_RX->Data_suhu;
       if(bufferString == "Data Stop")
       {
         ad_log_Serial("AT89S52 -> "+BUF_RX->Data_suhu,clRed);
       }
       else
           {
         ad_log_Serial("AT89S52 -> "+IntToStr(bufferInteger),clRed);
         txtTemp->Text = IntToStr(bufferInteger).c_str();
       }
       LedRx->States->Items[0]->Value = true;
     }
     else
     {
        LedRx->States->Items[0]->Value = false;
     }
 }__finally
 {
     delete(BUF_RX);
 }
}
```

what should i do this code?

Comment: Why are you converting a `String` to `int`, just to convert it to `String` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `bufferInteger` assignment to the `else` clause:

```
else
{
    bufferInteger = StrToInt(BUF_RX->Data_suhu);
    ad_log_Serial("AT89S52 -> "+IntToStr(bufferInteger),clRed);
    txtTemp->Text = IntToStr(bufferInteger).c_str();
}
```

Since it's not being used outside it, there's no point in having it there. And assuming that any string that's not `"Data Stop"` is supposed to represent an integer, the code will not fail this way.